# Reference request: convergence in distribution of $c_nX_n$.

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Is this result proved in any books?

> Assume that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in distribution to
>   $X$. Also assume that $c_n$ is a sequence of real numbers which
>   converges to $c$. Then $(c_nX_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in
>   distribution to $cX$.

Have you seen this result in any texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem), pretty much. It is discussed in many texts, including Billingsley's.